# Domo - Equivalent to Tableau Parameter

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, domo

zI'm a Tableau user and want to identify if something similar to Tableau parameters are in Domo.  Here is what I am doing in Tableau:

dataset is all ZIP codes and multiple numeric columns

I built a Tableau boolean parameter for each of the numeric columns

I then made a Calculated Field for each of the numeric columns: where if the boolean parameter==TRUE, then the calc'd field yields the original column's value; else, it yields 999 (a big number as compared to all the other numeric columns)

I then have another calc'd column that finds the minimum of all the other calc'd fields.  The result is that I can color a map by ZIP code based upon the lowest numeric value *but only those columns that have their boolean==TRUE*

Is this possible in Domo?  I've heard Domo doesn't have ZIP shapefiles, just ZCTAs, and that is probably OK... but I want to have the flexibility to use all these boolean parameters and then color the map as a downstream effect of all the booleans.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Domo Beast Mode Calculation [The 'Add Calculation' option within a card/graph view.

You can use the case statement to:

- Specify a condition. E.g. - (Case if 'column_1' = 'TRUE' then 'column_2' else 'column_3')
- You can also find the minimum value in a column using the 'MIN' function within the beast mode

If you still need help, then you can post your question within Domo Dojo and someone from Domo support or from the community will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to unpivot to put the two metrics in a single column, then use a filter to select the metric.